# Better Information On Defense Damage Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

The way that Clash of Clans chooses to convey information about how much damage defense buildings output is bad. The current method of telling the user that a mortar does X dmg a second is pretty worthless since they fire much slower than once a second.

Where can I find a break down / what is the damage break down for how much damage these buildings do per **shot** rather than per **second**?

Sure, information on each level of the buildings would be nice but if that is too much I think simply providing the data for level one of each building would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clash of Clans Wikia has a breakdown of all defenses and their damage rate per shot, including the splash radius where applicable.  For instance, see [this page for the Mortar](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Mortar).

At level 1, the Mortar does 20 damage per shot (= 4 damage/sec) with a 1.5 tile splash radius.

I don't want to completely reproduce their tables, but you can get an index of all the defensive buildings [on this page.](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Defensive_Buildings)

Comment: Does the mortar do 20 damage to everything in the damage radius?

Comment: @Caleb, in my experience, yes.  I often send barbs/archers up against mortar shots, and it looks like they take consistent damage regardless of where in the shot they are standing.